# Django CreateView redirect to ListView when form invalid

Tags: django, django-views

i have `views.py` like this

```
class InventoryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'inventorys'
    model = models.Inventory

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InventoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = InventoryForm()
        return context

class InventoryCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'sn', 'desc', 'employee')
    model = models.Inventory
```

and here my `models.py`

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sn = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='Empty')
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='employee')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("system:inventory_list")
```

and here my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^invn/$',views.InventoryListView.as_view(), name='inventory_list'),
url(r'^invn/create$',views.InventoryCreateView.as_view(), name='inventory_create'),
```

and here my `inventory_list.html`

```
{% for inventory in inventorys %}
  <td>{{ inventory.name }}</td>
{% endfor %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'system:inventory_create' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

if the form is valid, its work well.

But if the form is invalid it will redirect to `inventory_form.html` that will cause `TemplateDoesNotExist` since Django `CreateView` need `inventory_form.html` (CMIIW).

simple solution create `inventory_form.html` but that not what I want.

how to make it redirect to my `ListView` when the form is invalid with error messages ?...

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to redirect to `ListView`.

Just override `form_invalid()` in `CreateView`.

Default `form_invalid()` is below

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

You can redirect to your `ListView`.

But the problem is, when redirect, you cannot pass any context or message to them. It just redirects to your listview.

So you have few choices.

First, you can keep `form_invalid()` the same, and if form is invalid (you can check it with error with `form.errors`) show alert error message in the CreateView page with alert or confirm, and when click ok, redirect to listview page.

Second, you can use `session`. Before redirect to listview, you can give some session data for deciding it's from invalid CreateView.

I think first one is better approach for web.

If you have any question, just comment it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible to redirect User inside `form_invalid()` method, and use the [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages), to alert the user (Error Message).

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class InventoryCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'sn', 'desc', 'employee')
    model = models.Inventory  


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        'form is invalid'
        messages.add_message(self.request,messages.WARNING,"Form is invalid")
        return redirect('inventory_list')
```

To retrieve the message in template:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```